# Software that generates Android-style documentation diagrams?

Tags: android, uml

I think the title says it all: do you know what software was used to generate Android documentation diagrams? I like it.

I know that you can customize the design of Visio or even dot (graphviz) diagrams to look like this, but I'm curious.

See below for an example link and a reference image:

[image]
Source: [Starting an Activity: Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.